# how to concatenate a list of a list of strings

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, map, concatenation

I have two lists of lists, `La` and `Lb` that I want to concatenate so that every element of a list n in La is concatenated with the corresponding element of list n in `Lb`.  For example:

```
La = {{P, O, O, O}, {C, O, O, C, N}};

Lb = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {9, 8, 7, 6, 5}};
```

with the desired result:

```
Lc = {{P1, O2, O3, O4}, {C9, O8, O7, C6, N5}};
```

I assume there is an easy way to do this, but I'm new to *Mathematica*.

Comment: `Apply[StringJoin, Transpose /@ Transpose[{La, Lb}], {2}]`...

Comment: It is not clear if your input lists `La` and `Lb` contains already strings or symbols and numbers. Please edit your post to format properly the code part of your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an approach for any two multi-dimensional lists of strings which have arbitrary, but matching structures:

```
stringJoin[x__String] := StringJoin[x]
SetAttributes[stringJoin, Listable]
stringJoin[La, Lb]
```

**EDIT**
Short explanation of listability:

> Listable functions are effectively applied separately to each element in a list, or to **corresponding** elements in each list if there is more than one list.

In order to prevent premature evaluation of `stringJoin[a,b]` where `a` and `b` are lists, e.g. `a = {a1,a2,a3}; b = {b1,b2,b3}` leading to `"a1a2a3b1b2b3"` I have `stringJoin` accept only `String` arguments. Then it keeps drilling down to the lowest level until it finally does find a string.

Here's another example. Setting a function `f` to be listable is almost like replacing every occurrence of `f[...]` with `Thread[f[...]]`.

```
list = {a, b, {c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k}}
f[list, list]
(* f[{a, b, {c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k}},
      {a, b, {c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k}}] *)
```

Now:

```
Thread[f[list, list]]
```

`{f[a, a], f[b, b],`
**`f[{c, d}, {c, d}], f[{e, f, g, h}, {e, f, g, h}],  f[{i, j, k}, {i, j, k}]}`**

`ReplaceRepeated` can allow emulation of listability:

```
f[list, list] //. f[x_, y_] :> Thread[f[x, y]]
(* {f[a, a], f[b, b], {f[c, c], f[d, d]}, {f[e, e], f[f, f], f[g, g], f[h, h]}, {f[i, i], f[j, j], f[k, k]}} *)
```

Or we can simply do `SetAttributes[f, Listable]; f[list, list]`.

Comment: Clever. +1 for out-of-the-box thinking.

Comment: @ciao It's because every time I see a task like this and read the answers I'm already expecting a follow-up comment "but with `La={{a,b,c,{d,e,f}},{g,h,i}}` it doesn't work." Also the arrays in OP are ragged.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP .... but it works with the OP's arrays

Comment: @belisarius certainly, I'm not bashing anyone's answer, just trying to think a step ahead. As in if right now they're simply ragged, the next moment they could be multi-levelled with strings appearing not just at depth of 2.

Comment: Well. I understand your concerns. But within its validity scope your answer is as elegant as they can go

Comment: @belisarius - agreed re: elegance, and *LLlAMnYP*: I hear you, few things irk me more than a question that gets answered with neat solutions only to have OP edit with "well, no, what I *meant* was... and it needs this and that too..." instead of providing that from the start. (n.b., I am *not* saying this question is one of those, just commenting on a shared frustration!)

Comment: @ciao It's not even the fear of a follow-up question, it's just that I feel that a general solution has more lasting value to those, who might show up several months later and read it, then a solution that works in a very specific case. Maybe not OP, but another user will ask "what if I have more complex lists", but he won't have to make a new question - my answer will work for him too. Also I get more satisfaction out of solving a generalized problem, unless of course performance starts to suffer significantly.

Comment: I was not really aware that `Listable` could thread that way ! +1 I think it is worth explaining a little bit more how this works ;)

Comment: It's actually good practice to anticipate use cases as reasonably broad as possible when writing something for public consumption, so I commend you for your efforts.

Comment: @SquareOne detailed explanation is done.

Answer (score 6):

```
sLa = Map[ToString, La, {2}];
sLb = Map[ToString, Lb, {2}];
MapThread[StringJoin, #] & /@ Transpose[{sLa, sLb}]
```

also

```
Thread[j @@ #] & /@ Transpose[{sLa, sLb}] /. j -> StringJoin
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Plus` already does the element-wise addition, you can do:

```
La + Lb /. Plus -> (List /* Map[ToString] /* StringJoin)
```

This assumes the elements won't be destroyed by the plus, but as described by LLlAMnYP you can just Listableize the function:

```
Function[{a, b}, StringJoin[ToString /@ {a, b}], Listable][La, Lb]
```

or ToString before the operation:

```
Plus @@ Map[ToString, {La, Lb}, {-1}];
% /. Plus -> StringJoin
```